# enter the text in text box that similar text for retrieve the data into the drop down list in php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, javascript-objects

I have dropdown list connect with database in my database.there have two colum `idno` and `name`. My dropdown list works perfectly but I need to show, when I enter the `idno` in text box that similar idno for retrieve the `name` into the dropdown list with out any button submition. Please can any one help me.
Here is my index.php file

```html
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('test');

$sql = "SELECT name FROM schol";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
?>

<body>
  <form name="form1" method="post" id="form1" action="">
    <table class="form" >
      <tr>
            <td>Item:</td>
            <td>Id no</td>   
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input name="itemid"  type="text" id="itemid"/></td>   
        <td><?php echo "<select name='dropdwn'>";
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<option value='" . $row['idno'] ."'>". $row['name'] ."</option>";
              }
            echo "</select>";?>
        </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
 </form>
</body>
```

Comment: you have no submit button, and your form tag is unclosed

Comment: Refrain from using `mysql_*` syntax, they are already depecrated.

Comment: sorry form tag i miss it,but that is not a matter

Comment: is that possible to retrieve with out click the submit button??

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps 
On blur event of text box 
    var your_text_box_value=$('#your text id').val();
    $('#select_bix_id option[value="' + your_text_box_value + '"]').attr("selected", "selected");

Comment: thank you sir.how can i connect to dropdown list sir.

Answer (score -1):

You can do that in JS/jQuery like below. 
NOTE: Don't forget to add jquery in your head tag for this to work.

```
 <input type="text" id="optValue" />
        <div id="opValues">
            <select id="optionSel">
                <option value="1">One</option>
                <option value="2">Two</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <script>
            $("#optValue").keyup(function() {                                                           
                $.get( "products.php?id=" + $(this).prop("value"), function( data ) {
                  $( "#opValues" ).html( data );                  
                }); 
            });
        </script>
```

PHP code: (products.php)

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('test');

$sql = "SELECT name FROM schol WHERE idno = %d";

$result = mysql_query(sprintf($sql, $_GET['idno']));

$ret = "<select>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $ret .= "<option value=" . $row["idno"] . ">". $row["name"] ."</option>"
}
$ret .= "</select>" 

echo $ret;
?>
```

Comment: thank you sir,but here drop down also retrieve the data in db.how can i add that to this

Comment: What is your real use case? You want to retrieve asynchonousely from db every time an id is entered in textbox? or (from your code above) you are retrieving from db once and generate the select options and then after, when the page is finish loading, if user entered an id in textbox then you need your select option to select the item with that id no? which is which?

Comment: yes sir i need to want to retrieve asynchonousely from db every time an id is entered in textbox.

Comment: With that, it means that you always have a single item in your select option, right? So what is the point of having the select option?

Comment: yes sir.in above code i try to do that,but i haven't clear idea about how can i use that code,

Comment: Hi please take a look in my updated answer, that should give you an idea.